# How to set right charset to working throw proxy-server with jsoup?

Tags: java, character-encoding, proxy, jsoup

This code gave me content but some russian characters hide for me for square... Who know how to set utf-8 or cp1251 charset for proxy to get content. Dance with code do not take any results for me. getBytes and other method can't give me normal result.

```
URL url = new URL(linkCar);
String your_proxy_host = new String(proxys.getValueAt(xProxy, 1).toString());
int your_proxy_port = Integer.parseInt(proxys.getValueAt(xProxy, 2).toString());
Proxy proxy = null;
System.out.println(proxys.getValueAt(xProxy, 3).toString());
proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(your_proxy_host, your_proxy_port));
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(proxy);
connection.setConnectTimeout(16000);
connection.connect();
```

proxys - table model where list of the proxies;
And may be who know how to set connect throw socks-proxy

Comment: what code follows this ? where is the code that is actually reading content from the connection ?

Comment: Here are! Sorry!

    String line = null;
    StringBuffer buffer_page = new StringBuffer();
    BufferedReader buffer_input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream())); 
    While ((line = buffer_input.readLine()) != null) {
    buffer_page.append(line);
    }
    doc = Jsoup.parse(String.valueOf(buffer_page));
    connection.disconnect();

Comment: you should post the code above as an edit to your original question. It's almost impossible to read code in a comment since it can't be formatted. 1+ to @A.J. for his answer.

Comment: sorry! I can't! reputation....

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels thank you :)

Comment: @Trump: if you *accept* A.J.'s answer, you'll get some rep. I've already given you some by up-voting your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for UTF-8, try to change the line

```
BufferedReader buffer_input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
```

to

```
BufferedReader buffer_input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));
```

you can change the charset name to another one if you want to change the charset.